# Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am just trying to execute the "select" sql statement using TADOQuery component, but when TADOQuery's "Open" statement is executing I am getting following error:

```
Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset...
```

```
ADOQuery1.Active := False;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select * from Table1 where Column1 = <value>');
ADOQuery1.Open;
```

Any guess why I am getting this error ?

Comment: If you're having some issue in D7, you should not add label for 2010 or 2009.

Comment: Please show us the code. Without the code we can do nothing more than guess.

Comment: Are there event handlers (OnBeforeOpen) or master/detail datasources attached to the query? You can also use a tool like madExcept to find the exact code location where the exception occurs, as it will be shown with source file name and line number.

Comment: Code doesn't work in comments. Please edit the question to include code.

Comment: Is a TDatasource connected with the AdoQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine.

Check if there are any event handlers (OnBeforeOpen) or master/detail datasources attached to the query. In this case a different dataset, which is still closed, could cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, I am using SQL Server 2008 as database.

Here "SetAppRole" was not applied on the database, after applying it, now there is no error.