# SQL database corrupt after uploading (Android)

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to upload several SQL databases from Android to an online server using the following code:

```
public static void uploadFile(String file,String folder) {

HttpURLConnection conn = null;


String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
try {
    // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
    path));

    // open a URL connection to the Servlet

    URL url = new URL("http://myserver/upload_file.php");

    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Allow Outputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    // Don't use a cached copy.
    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // Use a post method.
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=uploadedfile;filename="
        + path + "" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    // create a buffer of maximum size

    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    int maxBufferSize = 1000;
    // int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];

    // read file and write it into form...

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bytesAvailable = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
    }

    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // close streams

    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
}

try {
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
    .getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message: " + line);
    }
    rd.close();

} catch (IOException ioex) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
}
return;
}
```

All appears to go well, but if I try to open the resulting file with SQLite Administrator it is throwing an error reading "Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset".

Does anyone have an idea why this may be happening? File size of the original and the copy appear to be the same.

**UPDATE 1:
Here is the error thrown by my app if trying to access the database:**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: malformed database schema (?) (code 11): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Table
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Are you using SQL server 2008 ?

Comment: If you are using SQL server 2008, then you might not have  applied the `setAppRole` to the database. This might lead to this problem . Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288084/cannot-perform-this-operation-on-a-closed-dataset

Comment: I am not using an SQL server online.  I am only backing up the file to be shared and used locally on the device of of other users.

Comment: This might have to do with different sqlite versions. If I understand correctly you move a database from device A to B and try to open it there?

Comment: That is correct.  The error I noted above happens when trying to open the DB with SQLite Administrator.  I've added the error thrown by the device if you try to access the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was that I was uploading a SQL database file without and extension added to it.  After adding a .DB to the end all uploaded well.

As a followup, can anyone tell me of renaming the file adding the DB and then stripping it back off after downloading will work?  If not I will have to tear through thousands of lines of code that reference the DB names.